# custom image url rewrite to directory using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have currently mod_rewrite enabled on https://abcd.com/images/12345_image_67890.jpg which streams the image through a PHP file image.php

Now what I am trying to do is rewrite the https://abcd.com/images/12345_image_67890.jpg to the source directory/file -> image_directory/4590/12345.jpg

```
12345 in the filename12345_image_67890.jpg is image_id
67890 in the filename 12345_image_67890.jpg is post_id
```

The problem: if you see the subdirectory 4590 inside the image_directory which was dynamically created while uploading the file and 4590 directory name was generated using the last 2 digits of image_id and post_id
How can I get 45, 90 and 12345 from this url -> https://abcd.com/images/12345_image_67890.jpg and rewrite it to image_directory/4590/12345.jpg
I know this is confusing, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/\d{3}(\d{2})_image_\d{3}(\d{2}).jpg$
RewriteRule ^images/(\d{5})_image.*\.(.*)$ /image_directory/%1%2/$1.$2 [R=302,NC,L,NE]
```

In case you don't want to redirect url in browser then you could remove `R=302` in above solution.

Comment: thanks for the answers. The solution works but what can be done when the length of image_id and post_id is not fixed (5). In some cases it can be 8 digits and 12 digits. Do you have any idea how we can implement that ?

Comment: @Abhinav, sure you could use either `\d{1,n}` or `\d+` etc and try. Please do let me know in case of any more queries here, cheers.

Comment: @Abhinav, Could you please do let me know if there are 8 to 12 digits are there then how many yo want to capture out of them?

Comment: What worked for me is:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/\d{1,12}(\d{2})_image_\d{1,12}(\d{2}).*$
RewriteRule ^images/(\d{1,12})_image_(\d{1,12})\.(.*)$  /image_directory/%1%2/$1.$3 [NC,L,NE]